# pyOpenGL color picking on windows

Tags: opengl, wxpython, pyopengl

I have wxPython + pyOpenGL application that needs to be cross platform. Now for selection I implemented a color picking scheme, basically as follows:

```
if len(self.pick_color_array) == 0:
    self.init_color_buffers(len(self.points))
glUseProgram(0)
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
glDisable(GL_BLEND) 
glDisable(GL_DITHER)
glDisable(GL_FOG) 
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING) 
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_1D) 
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) 
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_3D) 
glShadeModel(GL_FLAT)
glPushMatrix()           
glTranslate(self.x_translation_step,self.y_translation_step, 
                        Z_DISTANCE + z_translation)

glRotate(alpha_rotation, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
glRotate(beta_rotation, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
self.apply_connectivity_nose_correction()
for i in range(len(self.points)):
     glColor3ub(self.pick_color_array[i][0], self.pick_color_array[i][1], self.pick_color_array[i][2])
     glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY) 
     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.positions_buffers[i][0])
     glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.positions_buffers[i][2])

     glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.positions_buffers[i][2])
     glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, None) 
glPopMatrix()
viewport = glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT)
pixel = glReadPixels(self.control.mouse_x(), float(viewport[3] - float(self.control.mouse_y())), 1, 1, 
                     GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
glUseProgram(self.shader.shader)
glEnable(GL_BLEND) 
glEnable(GL_DITHER)
glEnable(GL_FOG) 
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING) 
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_1D) 
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) 
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D) 
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
```

Now for the init_color_buffers:

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    self.pick_color_dict = {}
    self.pick_color_array = []
    vertices = numpy.array([
         0.0,  1000.0,  0.0,
        -1000.0, -1000.0,  1000.0,
         1000.0, -1000.0,  1000.0,
         0.0,  1000.0,  0.0,
         1000.0, -1000.0,  1000.0,
         1000.0, -1000.0, -1000.0,
         0.0,  100.0,  0.0,
         1000.0, -1000.0, -1000.0,
        -1000.0, -1000.0, -1000.0,
         0.0,  1000.0,  0.0,
        -1000.0, -1000.0, -1000.0,
        -1000.0, -1000.0,  1000.0
    ], dtype=numpy.float32)
    buffer_cube = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer_cube)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ADT.arrayByteCount(vertices), 
                    ADT.voidDataPointer(vertices), GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    glUseProgram(0)
    glDisable(GL_BLEND) 
    glDisable(GL_DITHER)
    glDisable(GL_FOG) 
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING) 
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_1D) 
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) 
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_3D) 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()     
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT)   
    for i in range(nr_points):
        self.pick_color_array.append((numpy.uint8(255.0/nr_points*i), 
                                      numpy.uint8(255 - 255.0/nr_points*i), 
                                      numpy.uint8(255.0/nr_points*i)))
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glColor3ub(self.pick_color_array[i][0], self.pick_color_array[i][1], self.pick_color_array[i][2])
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY) 
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer_cube)
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12) 
        pixel = glReadPixels(10, 10, 1, 1, 
                     GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
        from binascii import hexlify
        bit_repr = bin(int(b"1" + hexlify(pixel), 16))[3:]    
        color_0 = 0
        for bit in bit_repr[:8]:
            color_0 = color_0 * 2 + numpy.uint8(bit)
        color_1 = 0
        for bit in bit_repr[8:16]:
            color_1 = color_1 * 2 + numpy.uint8(bit)
        color_2 = 0
        for bit in bit_repr[16:]:
            color_2 = color_2 * 2 + numpy.uint8(bit)              
        self.pick_color_dict[(color_0, color_1, color_2)] = i
```

Now this was written and worked perfectly on MacOS. But now when I try it on windows it won't work at all. The color dictionary that is created is just a {(0, 0, 0): last_index} and also any click on any of my items also returns (0, 0, 0). Now I'm really stumped as to what I'm doing wrong here, especially since on MacOS everything works fine. My only guess would be that either glReadPixels somehow doesn't work properly on windows or wxPython on windows somehow messed it up?!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Bogdan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting up any viewport in init_color_buffers, that may be the reason the calls to glReadPixels() return black pixels. Also, projection matrix is not being set. Maybe the order of calls is a little bit different on Mac and on Windows (hard to say without complete source code).

On windows, glViewport() is usually called at the point the window is first displayed, after OpenGL is initialized. That may be well after the point when init_color_buffers is called. The window should, in general, be visible in order for glReadPixels() to return something.

Try using lazy initialization (make sure the window is visible before calling init_color_buffers).

Also, you can use glGetIntegerv() with GL_RED_BITS, GL_GREEN_BITS and GL_BLUE_BITS in order to calculate correct colors without the need to readback (also, your code is not using all the colors it can, it can only display up to 256 distinct colors, but with 8-bit RGB it is possible to display 2^24 colors).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll give the suggestions a try. I know I'm not using all colors but since I only need a maximum of 120 colors I didn't want to complicate any further.

Comment: Also the projection matrix is set once in initGl that is called before any of these with gluPerspective(45.0, ratio, 0.1, 800.0) and after that it doesn't change at all. Should I still call it again in init_color_buffers?

Comment: That is not neccessary then. It should work on Windows as well in case it worked on Mac. I also noticed a small error in your vertex data, the y coordinate of the 6th vertex is 100 where it should probably be 1000. But that shouldn't affect anything.